# ZF2 Fatal error AbstractActionController not found on shared host

Tags: php, controller, zend-framework2, shared-hosting

I developped my app localy (where it runs fine) and wanted to upload it to a shared host to test it.
Now I get an Fatal error that says the Zend DefaultController is not found when I go to any page on my app, only the index page works... The indexcontroller also extends Default controller as my other controllers does.

the test version is visible on tbox.ues.ch, this page will work but when you go to tbox.ues.ch/tender for example it throws the error.

my code on this line is simply

```
use Zend\MVC\Controller\AbstractActionController ;

class TenderController extends AbstractActionController 
{...
```

nothing special like you can see

I'm using zendskeletonapplication and my .htaccess at root folder contains

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

I already searched arround, tried out several htaccess configuration, but didn't find a solution. Problem is still the same, even if I access my app on tbox.ues.ch/public with the default .htaccess from ZF2

Does somebody has any Idea?

Comment: It says something totally different. Fatal error: Class 'Zend\MVC\Controller\AbstractActionController' not found in /var/www/clients/client4/web5/web/module/Tender/src/Tender/Controller/TenderController.php on line 23

Comment: nevermind, problem is the same.

Comment: What is this "DefaultController" you are talking about? The package Zend\Mvc\Controller\ does not contain a "DefaultController" from the usual setup. Did you write this DefaultController yourself? Do you want to use AbstractActionController or AbstractController in any case? Because these two are in Zend\Mvc\Controller

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion, I'm trying out many differten things to try  to debug. The one I want to use is AbstracActionController from Zend ('Zend\MVC\Controller\AbstractActionController'), which works fine on my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my error...
I changed Zend\MVC... to Zend\Mvc... uppercase problem

But I find strange that it works on my localhost and not on my shared host, anyway now I know from where comes my problem